# Setting ngStyle based on dynamic data

Tags: angular

I have an SVG that contains a path element. I want the fill and stroke to be set based on the value of an array called `shirts`.

```
<path class="st2" style="stroke-width:2.0;" [ngStyle]="myStyle(4)" d="M11.5,315....315.9z"/>
```

My `myStyle` function is:

```
myStyle(p): Object {
    return {
        fill: this.shirts[p]
    }
}
```

And then within my component I have:

```
shirts: any = [];

setShirts(shirts) {
    this.shirts = shirts;
}
```

I am then calling `setShirts` to set the value of `shirts`

My problem is that at the point that the SVG is displayed the value of `shirts` is empty. A fraction of a second later `setShirts` kicks in and `shirts` is set to be an array of colours.

How do I get `myStyle` to check `shirts` only after the colours have been set by `setShirts` ?

Comment: when are you calling the function setShirts?

Comment: I am calling this from another component, this.player.setShirts(this.firebaseGameData.shirts);   If I add a console.log to setShirts then I can see that the correct data is being set

Comment: You just have to make sure that your function is called before view rendering. Otherwise we will have a workaround.

Comment: Yes, sounds exactly like what I need ... but how do I prevent the view rendering until I am ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can call your function in ngOnInit() or we can try this:

In HTML:

```
<path *ngIf="isListLoaded" class="st2" style="stroke-width:2.0;" [ngStyle]="myStyle(4)" d="M11.5,315....315.9z"/>
```

In ts:

```
isListLoaded :any = false;

setShirts(shirts) {
    this.shirts = shirts;
    this.isListLoaded = true;
}
```

**Updated**:

Import ChangeDetectorRef in player.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject and instantiate it in player.ts

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
}
```

And finally

```
setShirts(shirts) {
    this.shirts = shirts;
    this.isListLoaded = true;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I actually tried something very similar to your second approach earlier today. It doesn't work, the value of isListLoaded becomes true but this doesn't make any difference to the <path> elements in my SVG, they're still hidden

Comment: Does changed value of boolean variable reflected in view?

Comment: No, I see always see false in the view. But if I console log this.isListLoaded in setShirts then I can see the value is being changed to true

Comment: Tried [ngStyle]="(shirts.length >0) ? myStyle(4) : ' ' "  ?

Comment: Is setShirts and element resides in same component?

Comment: Yes. setShirts() is inside player.ts, my view is player.html. I am calling this.player.setShirts(blah); from game.ts.

Comment: See the updated solution. Your variables are not detecting changes in view as they are being updated by another file.

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) is how it works. See if you are missing something.

Comment: Do I need to make anything @Injectable() ?

Comment: I could help better if you can upload the code somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172518/discussion-between-prachi-and-chris).